# Pandas: Ignore specific (bad) cells while doing sum(), mean() operations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to execute sum, mean operations on 'number' column using pandas library in python but some cells contains wrong data (2020-05-30) or they are empty. How can ignore those cells?

```
number
25
1
12
2020-05-30

6
7
...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Convert wrong values to missing values `NaN`s, pandas by default for `sum`, `mean` omit them:

```
df['number'] = pd.to_numeric(df.number, errors='coerce')
```

Or then remove rows with missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df['number'] = pd.to_numeric(df.number, errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['number'])
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:                                                                                                  
df['number'] = pd.to_numeric(df.number, error='coerce')
TypeError: to_numeric() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error'